# Finding Expression for Optimal Markowitz Weights

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, mean-variance, markowitz

So there are two assets with return rates $r_1$ and $r_2$ which have identical variances and a correlation coefficient $p$. The risk free rate is $r_f$.

I need to find an expression for the optimal Markowitz weights for the two assets.

The books says that the answer is ($s_1 - p s_2$)/[($s_1-s_2$)*($1-p$)], but I'm not sure how this makes any sense as I don't know what the s's mean.

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by "optimal"? are you trying to find the minimum variance portfolio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s_1 = r_1 -r_f$ and $s_2 =r_2-r_f$. Then, this is the maximization problem:
\begin{align*}
& \ \max_{w_1, w_2} SR = \frac{\mu_p}{\sigma_p}, \, \mbox{ subject to}\\
\mu_p = & \ w_1 s_1 + w_2 s_2,\\
\sigma_p^2 = & \ \sigma^2\big(w_1^2 + w_2^2 + 2 w_1 w_2 \rho\big),\\
1 = & \ w_1+w_2.
\end{align*}
By certain substitution, we convert the problem to the following
\begin{align*}
\max_{w_1} \frac{w_1(s_1-s_2)+s_2}{\sqrt{w_1^2 + (1-w_1)^2+2 w_1(1-w_1)\rho}} = \max_{w_1} \frac{w_1(s_1-s_2)+s_2}{\sqrt{2\big(w_1-w_1^2\big)(\rho-1) +1}}.
\end{align*}
From the first order condition,
\begin{align*}
(s_1-s_2)\big[2(w_1-w_1^2)(\rho-1)+1\big] -\big[w_1(s_1-s_2) + s_2\big](1-2w_1)(\rho-1)=0,
\end{align*}
we obtain that
\begin{align*}
(s_1-s_2) + w_1 (s_1-s_2) (\rho-1) - s_2(1-2w_1)(\rho-1)=0,
\end{align*}
and, consequently,
\begin{align*}
w_1 &= \frac{s_1-\rho s_2}{(s_1+s_2)(1-\rho)},\\
w_2 &= 1- w_1.
\end{align*}

Comment: I would think that you have a constrained convex problem and would need to solve it through lagrange multiplier method?

Comment: @emcor, if you have a constrained convex problem, then the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) theorem can be applied. For this question, the Lagrange multiplier method can also be applied, however, it will be much neater to deal with a single variable problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for the late answer. I hope you passed the exam anyway!

TO answer your question, $s_2 = r_2-r_f$, that is the excess return over the risk free rate/asset.

However, there seems to be a typo in your formula, I believe it should be

$w_1 = \frac{s_1-ps_2}{(s_1+s_2)(1-p)}$, i.e. plus in the denominator.

$w_1$ is the weight for asset 1 and $w_2 = 1-w_1$ the weight for asset 2 that maximize the Sharpe ratio.

Ohh, and Hi Mark Joshi! :) (in the comments)

Comment: Could you show us the derivation of this result? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the general solution (where $C$ is the covariance matrix of returns):[image]